# Where's genymotion path for android studio in Arch Linux?

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I set it to `/home/user/.Genymobile/Genymotion`, but android-studio still can't find it. I've googled and can't find people talking about this topic (linux). The [official guide](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#genymotion-plugin-for-android-studio) said the path is `/home/<user>/genymotion` and I don't have that path. So where is it?

**INFO:** *I'm running Arch Linux*

Comment: ermm.. how did you install Genymotion?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I installed using AUR (Arch User Repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where Arch usually puts installed packages, so I suggest you try to find the directory using the `find` command in the following places:

```
find /opt/ -iname *genymotion*
find /usr/ -iname *genymotion*
find /home/ -iname *genymotion*
```

Comment: Ah I see, It's in `/opt/genymotion`. I didn't check it before because usually Arch doesn't put AUR installation package there. Anyway, thanks for the hint